# How to end line with QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to create `QTextEdit` with some text, and in this text I have end of line characters (`\n`), but it is not accepted in `QTextEdit` object (whole text is displayed without any breaks). Any reason why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Qt 4.3 or later, then you can use [`setPlainText(const QString &text)`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop)

You can turn off rich text editing with [`setAcceptRichText(bool accept)`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtextedit.html#acceptRichText-prop) (Qt 4.1 or later)

Answer (score 3):

Per [the docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qtextedit.html#1), if you `setTextFormat(PlainText)` you should get what you want -- quoting with added emphasis:

> QTextEdit works on paragraphs and
>   characters. A paragraph is a formatted
>   string which is word-wrapped to fit
>   into the width of the widget. **By
>   default when reading plain text, one
>   newline signify a paragraph**. A
>   document consists of zero or more
>   paragraphs, indexed from 0. Characters
>   are indexed on a per-paragraph basis,
>   also indexed from 0. The words in the
>   paragraph are aligned in accordance
>   with the paragraph's alignment().
>   **Paragraphs are separated by hard line
>   breaks**. Each character within a
>   paragraph has its own attributes, for
>   example, font and color.

Comment: Funny enough, I seem not to have this function in my QTextEdit class. Any ideas why?

Comment: @atch, what version of Qt are you using?  Older versions didn't have that exact function (though there might be others you could use, depending on what version you're stuck with -- we, of course, have no way of guessing which Qt version you may be using!).

Comment: It could be a QT4 -> QT5 change.

Answer (score 0):

For `PyQt5`, new line was not showing rather entire text was shown as a string.

Firstly, set the object to accept rich text.

```
self.massorder.setAcceptRichText(True)
```

Secondly,

```
_data = self.massorder.toPlainText().split("\n")
```