# Why don't I have setTextFormat in my QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

Anyone have any Idea why I don't have this function (setTextFormat) in my QTextEdit class?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are using Qt 4 and there is no such function for QTextEdit instances. By the way what do you want to achieve by calling this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173151/how-to-end-line-with-qtextedit/2173273#2173273) to your previous question. QTextEdit API changed in Qt4

[QTextEdit docs for Qt 4.6](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtextedit.html)