# QTableWidget - putting multiple lines of text in one row

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to put multiple lines of text in one row of QTableWidget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think about 2 ways to force tablewidget to render multi-line text:

1. Setup [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstyleditemdelegate.html) item delegate and render text yourself in the delegates paint method. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334590/using-a-qstyleditemdelegate-on-a-qlistview-with-qsqlquerymodel/5346900#5346900) you can find an example of you could do the same thing to a listview.
2. Another solution would be to set QTextEdit as a cell widget to the table widget via [setCellWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) method.

Below is an example for #2:

```
QTableWidget* tableWidget = new QTableWidget(3, 2, this);
tableWidget->setGeometry(20, 20, 300, 300);

for (int row = 0; row<3; row++)
{
    for (int column=0; column<2; column++)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1 long long long long long long text").arg((row+1)*(column+1)));
        tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);
    }
    QTextEdit *edit = new QTextEdit();
    edit->setText(tableWidget->item(row, 0)->text());
    tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, 0, edit);
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: It seems that your link for "QStyledItemDelegate" is broken. A currently working link is this: [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html). The same for "setCellWidget": [QTableWidget::setCellWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget). (I would've fixed it by myself but the edit queue seems to be ful...)

Answer (score 6):

You can also simply use \n to start new line in a cell :-)

For example:

```
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(i);

    QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem("Line 1 \n Line 2");
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,newItem);
```

Comment: You may want to call ui->tableWidget->resizeRowToContents(i) afterwards, to make sure that the tablewidget shows the right height for the row

Comment: I did it this way and found out that if there is too many lines so height of row is over 5000, scrolling through table (especially over that row/s) will be very slow. Do you have solution for that?

Also I tried QTextEdit, scrolling over rows now works smootly enough but \n does not work in it. why?

Comment: You might read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173151/how-to-end-line-with-qtextedit to figure out how to set line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

just make vertical headers to fit the contents then use a text as long as you want.

```
QTableWidget::verticalHeader()->resizeSections(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for Python, but I'm not too familiar with C++.

According to Qt docs (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#details) resizing of horizontal and vertical headers behaves in same way:

> For a horizontal header the section is equivalent to a column in the model, and for a vertical header the section is equivalent to a row in the model.

So, when you want your last column to be as wide as the text, you do this:

```
self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(column_index, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
```

But in case of vertical header/vertical space you must do this:

```
self.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(row_index, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
```

Note that it is somewhat buggy/produces weird results which can be reset by resizing/clicking on the item, etc.