# How to put new line in QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am having trouble to put new line in QTableWidgetItem. Here is the code :

```
QTableWidget* item = new QTableWidgetItem;
item->setText("Line1 \n Line2");
```

With this code the item text is not displayed in two lines, i.e it seems that \n character is ignored.

I have a workaround to do this, with using QPlainTextEdit and the function setCellWidget, in that case everything work as expected but is more ugly, and I prefer not to make additional widget just to show text in multiple lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359017/qtablewidget-putting-multiple-lines-of-text-in-one-row

Comment: what does not work? the code you show or the accepted answer in the link??

Comment: sorry the code that I showed doesn't work. I guess I will have to use QLineEdit to show multi line text just like in the provided link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code is fine to separate lines. But you should change the size of each row to show multi-lines.

[image]

And after resizing row's height:

[image]

You see it's OK.